# Retrieve data from the given firebase data Structure

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Link to image]

I want to access article information but the problem I face is Article array names are some random keys and not like the one given here.

Comment: The Firebase documentation has a great page on [working with lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data) such as yours. If you're having problems making it work, show the [minimal code that reproduces where you're stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When doing so, also  replace the link to a screenshot of your database with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/).

Comment: If you're more a "learn by doing" learner, you can also take the [Firebase codelab for Android developers](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/), which covers reading of lists in step 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the keys inside the `Article` node, do the following:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("Branch").child("Users");
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
    String key=datas.child("keys").getValue().toString();

 }
}
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
  }
});
```

Here the datasnapshot is `Users` you then iterate inside the random keys and get the values(keys) that are inside the `Articles`.

Comment: I'm sorry I was doing a stupid mistake. Before I found it I commented here and then deleted it. It is working fine. Thanks for the answer